# YQL console not returning complete html page

Tags: select, yql

ok i will keep it simple

I put the following query in YQL [console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D90210&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Flaurenlemon%2Fstatus%2F470403949980549121%22)

```
select * from html where  url="https://twitter.com/laurenlemon/status/470403949980549121"
```

The twitter [site](https://twitter.com/laurenlemon/status/470403949980549121) in the query is a list of tweets which i want to pull using YQL.

The response in the console contained only the html tags and few contents of some of the html tags, but not a single tweets of any user was visible in any html element in response of the YQL console window.

I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys i figured it out,  YQL only has ability to scrape html loaded contents, now the contents that are loaded by AJAX like requests, so i had to go with selenium cum phantomJS that has ability to emulate a real browser and navigate to sites and scrape functions.
Anyone looking to scrape ajax loaded content can refer the selenium docs [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html), its very easy to use, step by step guide to scraping AJAX content.